# Are there scientific studies of remote-viewing with negative results?

Tags: esp

The Wikipedia page on [Remote Viewing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_viewing) says:

> A variety of scientific studies of remote viewing have been conducted. Some earlier, less sophisticated experiments produced positive results but they had invalidating flaws.[24] None of the more recent experiments have shown positive results when conducted under properly controlled conditions.

I have not found any Remote Viewing research results with negative results.

Comment: The problem is that it is much harder to find papers that show negative results... these are often simply not published in a scientific journal. I will try to search later, but I think I won't find anything

Comment: Related video: [Banned TEDTalk about Psychic Abilities | Russell Targ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBl0cwyn5GY)